# add a php variable within a href link

Tags: php, html

so I need to make a variable sub-domain to add to the end of a domain but it is not recogising the variable. in this example it would just go to google.com. anyone know the correct way of doing this?

```
<html>

  <?php $subdom="news";?>

     <a href="http://www.google.com/"<?php echo $subdom;?>>google</a>
</html>
```

Comment: A subdomain is should be somewhere after the second slash.

Comment: You should check the source of the html, then you would see directly what is wrong.

Comment: It's just a trivial mistake you've made. Look into your browsers source and compare what you wanted to achieve with what you achieved. Then review your code and locate the cause of the problem. Waiting for answers and just copying over pre-made solutions will hinder you to deal with these mistakes and will make your programming more hard. The more you train to spot these on your own, the less errors you will make over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will want to add the domain before the closing quotation sign to append it to the href variable instead of just adding it into the a tag.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/<?php echo $subdom;?>">google</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need

```
<html>

  <?php $path="news";?>

     <a href="http://www.google.com/<?php echo $path;?>">google</a>
</html>
```

And your variable name should probably be `$path` instead of `$subdom` since it actually holds a path and not a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

You have the echo in the wrong place. should be within the quotes.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/<?php echo $subdom; ?>">google</a>
```

And if you server has short open tags enabled you can do this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/<?=$subdom?>">google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/?subdom=<?php echo "$subdom"; ?>">google</a>
```